# Redshift Not Connecting to Host via Python Script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I currently have a .csv file in an S3 bucket that I'd like to append to a table in a Redshift database using a Python script. I have a separate file parser and upload to S3 that work just fine.

The code I have for connecting to/copying into the table is below here. I get the following error message:

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>       Is the server running on host "redshift_cluster_name.unique_here.region.redshift.amazonaws.com" (18.221.51.45) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5439?

I can confirm the following:

- Port is 5439
- Not encrypted
- Cluster name/DB name/username/password are all correct
- Publicly accessible set to "Yes"

What should I be fixing to make sure I can connect my file in S3 to Redshift? Thank you all for any help you can provide.

Also I have looked around on Stack Overflow and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance) but these seem to either be for MySQL to Redshift or the solutions (like the linked ServerFault CIDR solution) did not work.

Thank you for any help!

```
DATABASE = "db"
USER = "user"
PASSWORD = "password"
HOST = "redshift_cluster_name.unique_here.region.redshift.amazonaws.com"
PORT = "5439"
SCHEMA = "public"
S3_FULL_PATH = 's3://bucket/file.csv'
#ARN_CREDENTIALS = 'arn:aws:iam::aws_id:role/myRedshiftRole'
REGION = 'region'
############ CONNECTING AND CREATING SESSIONS ############
connection_string = f"redshift+psycopg2://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:{PORT}/{DATABASE}"
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string)
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
s = session()
SetPath = f"SET search_path TO {SCHEMA}"
s.execute(SetPath)
###########################################################
############ RUNNING COPY ############
copy_command = f
'''
copy category from '{S3_FULL_PATH}'
credentials 'aws_iam_role={ARN_CREDENTIALS}'
delimiter ',' region '{REGION}';
'''
s.execute(copy_command)
s.commit()
######################################
#################CLOSE SESSION################
s.close()
##############################################
```

Comment: What is the configuration of the **Security Group** associated with the Redshift cluster? Are you connecting from the Internet, or from EC2? Is the Redshift cluster in a public subnet?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for replying! The security group is still set to default - I created the cluster and am currently the only one accessing it. I am connecting to it from the internet, not EC2. 

I have made the cluster publicly accessible via [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cluster-private-public/)

Comment: Is the security group configured to permit port 5439 inbound from `0.0.0.0/0`? A timeout indicates that the client was unable to reach the cluster. Other things to check are that the cluster is in a public subnet. For testing purposes, you might want to use an SQL client like DBVisualizer. Are you able to connect to anything else in the same VPC (eg an Amazon EC2 instance)? That would help rule-out any networking problems.

Comment: I did not have that set up, no. I am now able to connect via the Python script (which has other issues that are separate).

This seemed to have caused another error though - I can now no longer see my database in Redshift when going through the query editor. When attempting to connect, I get the following message: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to 18.221.51.45:1130 [/18.221.51.45] failed: connect timed out.

Does this have anything to do with the change just made? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Most probably. What change did you make? It looks like it is trying to use port 1130, which is a bit unusual.

Comment: I don't think I made any changes besides that. I deleted/recreated the cluster (currently just learning the ropes with Redshift) but had the same VPC security group permissions attached, and it is now giving me the same error message that I had to begin with (except IP is now 3.132.158.123). I am allowing inbound traffic from my IP, 0.0.0.0/0, and 3.132.158.123/32. Is this worth going to AWS support over instead and posting back so that future folks can see the resolution? I'd feel bad taking up all of your time over it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Connecting via a Python program would require the same connectivity as connecting from an SQL Client.

I created a new cluster so I could document the process for you.

Here's the steps I took:

- **Created a VPC** with CIDR of `10.0.0.0/16`. I don't really need to create another VPC, but I want to avoid any problems with prior configurations.
- **Created a Subnet** in the VPC with CIDR of `10.0.0.0/24`.
- Created an **Internet Gateway** and attached it to the VPC.
- Edited the **default Route Table** to send `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to the Internet Gateway. (I'm only creating a public subnet, so don't need a route table for private subnet.)
- Created a **Redshift Cluster Subnet Group** with the single subnet I created.
- Launch a 1-node **Redshift cluster** into the Cluster Subnet Group. `Publicly accessible = Yes`, default Security Group.
- Went back to the VPC console to edit the **Default Security Group**. Added an Inbound rule for Redshift from Anywhere.
- Waited for the Cluster to become ready.
- I then used [DbVisualizer](https://dbvis.com/) to login to the database. **Success!**

The above steps made a publicly-available Redshift cluster and I connected to it from my computer on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you! I will run through this tonight.

Comment: Update, this worked! Looks like the major thing was adding the inbound rule for Redshift specifically, not All Traffic and designating 0.0.0.0/0. Thank you so much for your help over the last few days.

Comment: It worked for me, but I also had to create a new security group.