# Redshift Psycopg2 connection timeout - endpoint ip address is different

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a free tier redshift cluster through a python script on a local machine, and keep getting the following error:

```
> psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "<clusterendpoint>" (<clusterip>), port 5439 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I am using psycopg2 using the following code:

```
rs_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname= dbname,
    user= username,
    password= password,
    host = endpointurl,
    port = port)
```

My VPC is publicly available. I have tried adding my ip to the security group, and have also tried adding 0.0.0.0/0 to the security group, but haven't had any luck.

I used boto3 describeclusters() to investigate the problem further, and I did notice that neither the public nor private ip matched the ip shown in the error above associated with the endpoint url. Is that normal? I know that the endpoint url is correct.

Is there a better way to investigate this issue that will give me a better idea as to where the connection is going wrong?

Comment: Did you set the Redshift cluster **Publicly accessible** option to 'On'? (Note that this is a setting on the cluster, not the VPC. It is configured when launching the Redshift cluster.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the publicly accessible option is Enabled.

Comment: Was the Redshift cluster launched in a **public subnet**? That is, the subnet should have a Route Table that points to an Internet Gateway.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The subnet current points 0.0.0.0/0 to the internet gateway

Comment: The method here works for me: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399974/redshift-not-connecting-to-host-via-python-script)